Potential duplicates widget with Duplicate Record Set
I am trying to understand the Potential Duplicates lightning component that is now pretty often on the Account and Contact lightning page layouts. What indicates that something should show up as a duplicate?
I created a flow that would automatically identify certain things as duplicates, and adds them to a duplicate record set. This is not using duplicate rules or matching rules. But I still get the message "We found no potential duplicates of this Account." Does that only work with the matching rules?
I was hoping my users could use this component to easily merge duplicates, but it seems I might have to go back to the drawing board.

Just curious, are you also adding "DuplicateRecordItem"?

@MandyKool good question, yes the set also has two items, one for the account the flow was launched from and another for one that was identified with a lookup field in the flow because none of the match rules were stringent enough to catch it, but it didn't make sense to change the rules.

The "Potential Duplicates" lightning component in Salesforce relies on duplicate rules and matching rules to identify and display duplicate records. Here's a breakdown of how it works:

Duplicate Rules and Matching Rules:

Matching Rules: Define the criteria used to identify potential duplicates based on specific fields and conditions. For example, a matching rule might flag two accounts as potential duplicates if they have the same name and billing address.
Duplicate Rules: Use matching rules to evaluate records and determine whether to display a potential duplicate warning, allow or block the record from being saved, and take other actions like alerting the user.


Potential Duplicates Component:

The "Potential Duplicates" component checks the records against active duplicate rules when loading the page.
If a record matches the criteria defined in the duplicate rules, it will show as a potential duplicate.


I understood that your custom flow identify certain things as duplicates, and adds them to a duplicate record set independently of the standard duplicate rules and matching rules. Since the "Potential Duplicates" component relies specifically on duplicate rules and matching rules, it does not recognize records flagged by your flow.


To utilize the "Potential Duplicates" component for merging records, you need to set up matching rules and duplicate rules.
If you prefer to continue using your custom flow, you could enhance it to work alongside Salesforce's built-in duplicate management by incorporating matching rules and updating record sets.
